# How to implement atomic operation(s) on multi-core Cortex-M0/M0+ (no SWP, no LDREX/STREX)?

Tags: assembly, arm, atomic, multicore, cortex-m

Pre ARMv6 MPUs/MCUs have `SWP` instruction (e.g. good ole and still alive ARM7TDMI). In ARMv6 architecture `LDREX`/`STREX` pair has been introduced and `SWP` removed. However with one exception – ARMv6-M (Cortex-M0/M0+) has neither `LDREX`/`STREX` nor `SWP`. Strange.

So how to implement atomic operations/synchronization primitives on this platform? In the old-fashioned way using "enable interrupts"/"disable interrupts"? Or am I missing something? E.g. ChromiumOS uses [the old-fashioned method](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/ec/+/refs/heads/master/core/cortex-m0/atomic.h).

Disabling interrupts will work on single-core MCUs, **but what about multi-core MCUs**? Will this method work e.g. on a [RP2040](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf) (dual-core Cortex-M0+, the heart of [Raspberry Pi Pico](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-pico/))?

Comment: Yeah, disabling interrupts is the standard way on single-core microcontrollers.  LDREX/STREX needs a retry loop and the upside is that you avoid disabling interrupts for a very short time, so you're not hurting interrupt latency even a tiny amount.  I'd be surprised if there are modern multi-core systems without any way to do an atomic RMW, but I don't know which method is available on the CPU you're talking about.  Without that you might need [Dekker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) for a mutex; it requires only sequentially-consistent stores and loads, no RMW.

Comment: ldrex/strrex were not designed to replace swap.  they were designed for multi-core processors and support not required for single core.  even when the instructions are present it is up to the chip vendor.

Comment: so for these systems you should disable interrupts.

Comment: @old_timer: According to ARM they were: _Load-Exclusive and Store-Exclusive provide flexible and scalable synchronization, superseding the deprecated SWP and SWPB instructions._ – see document DHT0008A, page 1-4.

Comment: @old_timer They were definitely designed to replace `SWP` and in fact that is something you can do easily with them.

Comment: Note that the ChromiumOS method is interrupt-safe, but not atomic.  It won't work correctly e.g. in the presence of DMA.

Comment: @fuz I read the arm documentation it clearly stated that for uniprocessors exclusive access support was optional.  now on the software side it was implied, but on the axi side it was crystal clear that it was not.  Swap works with a single thread/vid and exclusive access specifically does not it is only to protect one virtual id from another not from itself, so it was not meant to replace swap it was a NEW thing for multiprocessor support to provide a mechanism to share across cores, beyond their L1 cache.

Comment: more than one chip vendor got caught up in this and the software folks went other way and those solutions did not work on these chips.  so now we would have to do tests outside the arm IP (l1 or l2 cache if you have one from them) to see if the chip vendor simply returned exok for exclusive and ok for non-exclusive or if they are actually keeping track of the last transaction per address range for some number of ranges since nobody can keep track of all ranges.  which also means for those that do support it how many concurrent locations are they tracking

Comment: ldrex/strex is very much misunderstood, unfortunately thanks to arms mess up with documentation, and even with cleaned up documentation, it does not do what you think it does.  certainly for a single core mcu there is no reason to support it so it is either going to show as an undefined instruction or it is going to give EXOK every time to make the software think it is happy.  this could be on other cortex-ms as well  explain how to get a different vid on the axi/ahb bus on those chips and we can do an easy experiment.

Comment: on a uniprocessor arm based chip, manage using interrupt disable or chip specific logic

Comment: you also see language like this "A slave that does not support exclusive accesses can ignore the AxLOCK signals. It must provide an OKAY response for both normal and exclusive accesses."  it is not assumed that a chip supports it.  granted if you want to run linux on that chip (full sized not cortex-m) that is how we found out about this with a big named company not supporting it.

Comment: @fuz What do you mean by "but not atomic"? Lack of memory barrier instruction(s) near ```CPSID```/```CPSIE```? I don't think they are necessary there as per _ARM Cortex™-M Programming Guide to Memory Barrier Instructions_ (DAI0321A). Besides isn't it what "memory" argument of gcc's inline assembly is for?

Comment: @jdx E.g. while you could implement [Dekker's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm) you could not implement a shared counter without locks as there is no way to do any atomic RMW operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unfortunate answer to this question is: you don't.  Atomic read/modify/write operations are not possible on the ARM Cortex-M0/M0+.  If you need such functionality, you'll have to rely on special purpose hardware.

For example, the RP2040 provides special memory regions for atomic RMW operations on peripherals.  It also provides a special spin lock peripheral for synchronisation between the two cores as well as hardware FIFOs for inter-core communication.  All of this is needed as the Cortex-M0+ core does not provide any atomic memory operations on its own.

Comment: Oh, I see, the SIO. I wonder if it is completely chip vendor specific or it has something to do with _Single-cycle I/O Port_ briefly mentioned in ARM's DUI0662B.

Comment: As this answer suggests, on RP2040 you have to use the HW spinlocks to implement your own synchronization mechanisms across both cores. Also see this API for reference: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/hardware.html#hardware_claim

Comment: Using the GNU atomic library (libatomic) will default to use some builtin functions that are not present on a Cortex M0+ target, like e.g. __atomic_fetch_add_4(...), etc. Also see: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libatomic

You can use the HW spinlocks of Pico, mentioned above, to implement your own versions of those builtin functions, then also granting synchronicity across both cores. Afaik, such an implementation is not available so far. If this was done, you are able to include and use the stdatomic library as intended.

Comment: @wiRe This is not possible as atomicity wrt DMA cannot be achieved.

Comment: @fuz You are right. DMA was not considered in my answer and must be covered separate, if required. But sometimes DMA can be excluded, if only the two M0+ cores of Pico are accessing some shared memory block.

Also keep in mind that I talk about a baremetal system (arm-none-eabi-gcc), which I expect to be the preferred choice for RP2040.

Comment: Also note that if a single spinlock is used to mediate all atomic operations, high congestion is to be expected.  It may be useful to use Dekker's or Peterson's algorithm instead.

Comment: You could also think of using multiple spinlocks and select them using parts of the shared memory address (similar to the concept of a direct mapped cache). Since spinlocks are used to lock only for very short times (few cycles) it must be considered if this is affordable or not from case to case. In the worst case you will loose CPU time and (since you may also wish to disable interrupts while a spinlock gets acquired; just to keep lock time small) increase your interrupt latency.

Comment: If atomic operations with spinlocks are not the best fit, consider to use a Mutex to protect a shared resource. Then algorithms like Dekker or Peterson might be a good choice. Or you can also use stdatomic or RP2040 HW spinlocks to implement your own Mutex. In case of a Mutex it can be implemented that the other core will only be locked if it asks for an already locked Mutex. And if you wish to use this waiting time for something useful, then go implement an RTOS on RP2040 like e.g. FreeRTOS.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep posting these below my answer.  We are veering more and more off topic.  I recommend that you post an answer on your own; comments are not for extended discussion.